# Typescript: Call function with generic syntax

Tags: typescript, generics

```
getData(): Observable<A | B> {
  return this.http.get<A | B>(this.requestURL, {});
}
```

If I remove `<A | B>` syntax next to the `get` method, `tslint` emits an error saying: `You can't bind Object to A or B` so, I wound up adding the syntax without understanding what's going on with the syntax. I looked up `Generics` in Typescript and the syntax seems to be used to capture the type the user provide. What confuses me is that according to the source code of the `get` method in `http` module in Angular 5 which I'm currently using, `get` method declaration doesn't use `generics`([`get` method source code](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.2/packages/http/src/http.ts#L130)). Besides, if the error occurs due to the type, wouldn't `return <Observable<A | B>>this.http.get(this.requestURL, {})` be correct?

To sum up, what's the point/purpose of using `Generics` syntax when calling a function like, `get<T>()` if the `get` method doesn't use the type information `T` in its declaration part?

Any insight would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found the source for the deprecated `Http` module (`@angular/http`). You are using the new module (`@angular/common/http`), which does have a generic `get` [method](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5.2.2/packages/common/http/src/client.ts#L765).

Using generic parameters on a method that does not define any is a compilation error, it has no meaning.

In the case of the `get` method, the type parameter is used to type the response. Not specifying the type parameter is an error in itself which can't be solved by casting (the cast `<Observable<A | B>>this.http.get(this.requestURL, {})` is invalid because the compilation error is already triggered by the invocation of `get` which is missing it's type parameters)